# modx ditto filtering

Tags: modx

I have this line of code:
[[Ditto? &depth=`3` &tpl=`@FILEweb_assets/chunks/x/x.html` &parents=`3` &filter=`template,7|endDate,[+now+],3`]]

The above line displays all items which using template 7. Now I want to make a change so that it will display all items with template 7 and 10. What should I do??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://ditto.modxcms.com/tutorials/basic_filtering.html) you can simply add another clause as follows

```
[[Ditto? &depth=3 &tpl=@FILEweb_assets/chunks/x/x.html &parents=3 &filter=template,7|template,10|endDate,[+now+],3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ditto provides parameter `&where`, which accept a valid MySQL WHERE statement. I guess it should help.

```
&filter=endDate,[+now+],3
&where=`template!=7 AND template!=10`
```